# Trying to set a variable in PHP.ini file under ubuntu 10.10

Tags: 10.10, php

I'm trying to set a variable in PHP.ini file under ubuntu 10.10. Namely the sendmail_path.

On my system there are 4 php.ini files:

- php.ini              at  /etc/php5/cli/
- php.ini-productions      at  /usr/share/php5/
- php.ini-productions.cli          at  /usr/share/php5/
- php.ini-productions-dist at  /usr/share/php5/

No other php.ini files are physically in/on my ubuntu 10.10 system.

I've altered all these files with `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t`
I'm testing ssmtp for other reason.

Starting `phpinfo()` under apache2 shows the variable `sendmail_path` still not getting the new value.

Copy from `phpinfo()` after restarting apache2:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/apache2 
Loaded Configuration File   (none) 
sendmail_path           /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Some more outputs from a terminal window:

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini

$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 11 2012 06:21:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

I'm in no way of solving this, and have tried to google for this behavior this weekend with no luck.

Regards to you if you can solve this, I guess I'm not the only one having this “issue”.

Comment: The output from Apache says it is searching in `/etc/php5/apache2`, so have you tried creating a `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file with the settings you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering myself this time.

Found a solution on this issue after say more googling and the page at:

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php

Really made my day.

Altered my empty httpd.conf file with the following:

```
php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/ssmtp -t"
```

Restarted apache2. No errors and phpinfo() shows the following at mentioned variable:

sendmail_path    /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Guess I can go of and testing more with ssmtp now.

And there are more about this at http://www.php.net